# Excel VBA - Looking up a string with wildcards

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Im trying to look up a string which contains wildcards. I need to find where in a specific row the string occurs. The string all take form of "IP##W## XX" where XX are the 2 letters by which I look up the value and the ## are the number wildcards that can be any random number. Hence this is what my look up string looks like :

```
FullLookUpString = "IP##W## " & LookUpString
```

I tried using the `Find` Command to find the column where this first occurs but I keep on getting with errors. Here's what I had so far but it doesn't work :L if anyone has an easy way of doing. Quite new to VBA -.-

```
Dim GatewayColumn As Variant
Dim GatewayDateColumn As Variant
Dim FirstLookUpRange As Range
Dim SecondLookUpRange As Range

FullLookUpString = "IP##W## " & LookUpString

Set FirstLookUpRange = wsMPNT.Range(wsMPNT.Cells(3, 26), wsMPNT.Cells(3, lcolumnMPNT))

Debug.Print FullLookUpString

GatewayColumn = FirstLookUpRange.Find(What:=FullLookUpString, After:=Range("O3")).Column

Debug.Print GatewayColumn
```

Comment: I don't think Find supports the use of wildcards that you need. You perhaps should look at the Like operator or regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comment by @SJR you can do this two ways. Using [`LIKE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/like-operator) the pattern is:

```
IP##W## [A-Z][A-Z]
```

Using regular expressions, the pattern is:

```
IP\d{2}W\d{2} [A-Z]{2}
```

Example code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindString()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- set your sheet
    Set rngData = ws.Range("A1:A4")

    ' with LIKE operator
    For Each rngCell In rngData
        If rngCell.Value Like "IP##W## [A-Z][A-Z]" Then
            Debug.Print rngCell.Address
        End If
    Next rngCell

    ' with regular expression
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim objMatch As Object

    Set objRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegex.Pattern = "IP\d{2}W\d{2} [A-Z]{2}"
    For Each rngCell In rngData
        If objRegex.Test(rngCell.Value) Then
            Debug.Print rngCell.Address
        End If
    Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Comment: I managed to get my head round it myslef eventually, my solution is similar to this just more suited to the spreadsheets that I'm working with but thanks alot for helping me understand the `Like` function

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that ALL the strings in the row match the given pattern, then we can examine only the last three characters:

```
Sub FindAA()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, Gold As String
    Set rng = Range(Range("A1"), Cells(1, Columns.Count))

    Gold = " AA"

    For Each r In rng
        If Right(r.Value, 3) = Gold Then
            MsgBox r.Address(0, 0)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If FullLookUpString Like "*IP##W##[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*" Then
    MsgBox "Match is found"
End If
```

It will find your pattern (pattern can be surrounded by any characters - that's allowed by `*`).